# Passing \* as a parameter for a parameter

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

Using ksh. Trying to reuse a current script without modifying it, which basically boils down to something like this:

```
 `expr 5 $1 $2`
```

How do i pass in a a multiplication command (*) as parameter $1 ?

I first attempted using "*" and even \* but that isn't working.
I've tried multiple escape backslash and quote combinations but i think im doing it wrong.

Comment: Change it to `expr 5 "$1" "$2"` then pass `'*'`. Note the single quote around `*`. That will prevent shell from expanding it to the filenames.

Comment: Thanks. But i would like to see if its possible without modifying the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without modifying the script, **I don't think this can be done**:

- On *calling*, you can pass a literal `*` as `'*'`, `"*"` or `\*` (any will do): this will *initially* protect the `*` from shell expansions (interpretation by the shell).
- The *callee* (the script) will then receive literal `*` (as `$1`), but due to *unquoted* use of `$1` *inside the script*, `*` will invariably be subject to filename expansion (globbing), and will expand to all (non-hidden) filenames in the current folder, breaking the `expr` command.
- **Trying to add an extra layer of escaping - such as `"'*'"` or `\\\*` - will NOT work**, because the extra escaping will become an *embedded, literal* part of the argument - the target script will see *literal* `'*'` or `\*` and pass it *as-is* to `expr`, which will fail, because neither is a valid operator.

---

Here's a **workaround**:

- Change to an *empty* directory.

  - By default, `ksh` will return any glob (pattern) *as-is* if there are no matching filenames. Thus, `*` (or any other glob) will be left unmodified in an *empty* directory, because there's nothing to match (thanks, [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)).
  - For the *calling* script / interactive shell, you could disable globbing altogether by running `set -f`, but note that this will not affect the *called* script.
- It's now safe to invoke your script with `'*'` (or any other glob), because it will simply be passed through; e.g., `script '*' 2`, will now yield `10`, as expected

  - If both the shell you invoke from *and* the script's shell are `ksh` (or `bash`) with their default configuration, you can even get away with `script * 2`; i.e., you can make do without quoting `*` altogether.

Comment: Or, with the default setting of `shopt -u nullglob failglob` (i.e. unset), you can do this in an empty directory.  A glob expression that doesn't match anything will remain unchanged as a single argument, instead of turning into a zero-length list.  Also, another way to phrase the reasoning for why passing in a `\*` doesn't work is that quote-removal happens *before* parameter expansion, so it doesn't happen on the result of parameter expansion.

Comment: @PeterCordes: As for the reasoning: actually, quote-removal is _part_ of parameter expansion, namely the _last step_. That is, when _calling_ the script, any _syntactic_ quote characters are removed just before the result is passed to the target program. Thus, by the time the argument values reach the script, the _extra_ layer of quoting has already become a _literal_ literal part of the arguments.  Inside the script, quote removal doesn't come into play, because the parameter references are unquoted themselves (and any quote chars _embedded_ in the values are treated as literals).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Excellent point re default globbing behavior if nothing matches, thanks - answer updated. Relying on globs to be passed as-is actually makes this solution much more generic. (As an aside: since this is `ksh`, Bash's `shopt` doesn't apply, but `ksh`'s defaults are the same, luckily.)

Comment: Thanks guys, i've never had to handle globs much before.

Answer (score 2):

Glob expansion happens very late, after parameter expansion, and word-splitting (in that order).  Quote-removal doesn't happen on the results of earlier expansions, just what was on the command line to start with.  This rules out passing in a quoted `\*` or similar (see mklement0's answer), by using an extra layer of quoting.

It also rules out passing in space-padded `*`:  Word-splitting removes the spaces before pathname (glob) expansion, so it still ends up expanding `*` to all the filenames in the directory.

```
foo(){ printf '"%s"\n' "$@"; set -x; expr 5 $1 $2; set +x; }
$ foo ' * ' 4
" * "
"4"
+ expr 5 ...contents of my directory... 4
expr: syntax error
+ set +x
```

You should fix this buggy script before someone runs it with an arg that breaks it in a dangerous way, rather than just inconvenient.

---

If you don't need to support exactly the same operators as `expr`, you might want to use arithmetic expansion to do it without running an external command:

```
result=$((5 $1 $2))   # arithmetic expansion for the right-hand side
# or
((result=5 "$1" "$2"))  # whole command is an arithmetic expression.
```

Double-quotes around parameters are optional inside an arithmetic expression, but you need to not use them in an arithmetic expansion (in bash.  Apparently this works in ksh).

Normally it's not a bad habit to just always quote unless you specifically want word-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: Actually, quote removal happens _last_:
"The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion."
"After all expansions, quote removal (see Quote Removal) is performed."
This is from the [`bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), but, given the similarities between `bash` and `ksh`, I  suspect it applies to `ksh` equally.
If you know of a `ksh`-specific reference, please let us know.

Comment: @mklement0: oh right.  I tend to think of the shell as removing the literal quote characters, and remembering which parts were quoted and which weren't.  Since quote-removal doesn't happen on the *result* of earlier expansions.  But you're right, the manual talks about it in the other order.  I think I have it described correctly in my first paragraph now.

Comment: I can see how that conceptualization makes sense; however, that Bash removes quotes _last_ is evidenced by the fact that your recommendation does NOT work in `bash`, given that arithmetic expansion happens first and breaks with double-quoted tokens: `operator='*'; operand='2'; echo $(( 2 "$operator" "$operand" ))` _breaks_ in `bash` (and also `zsh`), whereas it _works_ in `ksh` - contradicting my earlier assumption that `bash` and `ksh` work the same. Since this question is also tagged `shell`, please make it clear that your recommendation applies to `ksh` only.

Comment: @mklement0: thanks for catching that bug.  I had only tested with the `((result=5 "$1" "$2"))` form, where the quotes didn't matter one way or the other.  I did intend for this to work in bash, not just ksh, which I'm not really familiar with >.<   Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for updating. It may also be worth mentioning that you don't need the `$` prefix at all to use variables as _operands_ (though that won't work with the positional parameters `$1`, ... ; you also _always_ need the `$` to use a variable as an _operator_), though the behavior is then subtly different. If you find yourself playing with multiple shells regularly, let me (shamelessly) recommend [`shall`](https://github.com/mklement0/shall).